# AWS Cognito - ConfigError: Missing region in config for JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to call createIdentityPool from JavaScript SDK. Please find the below code from sample html screen -

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});    
AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  cognitoidentity: '2014-06-30',
  // other service API versions
};    
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();    
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region    
AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  cognitoidentity: '2014-06-30',
  // other service API versions
};        
var params = {    
AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true, // required     
  IdentityPoolName: 'String', // required    
  DeveloperProviderName: 'String',    
  OpenIdConnectProviderARNs: [    
    "my Pool Identity", // Identity Pool ID    
 ],
};    
cognitoidentity.createIdentityPool(params, function (err, data) {    
  if (err) alert(err, err.stack); // an error occurred    
  else     alert(data);           // successful response    
});
```

**Output alert is** -

> CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Can any one help me in this issue.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateIdentityPool must be called with your developer credentials.

You need to ensure that you have correctly initialized your SDK with AWS Credentials. Credentials can be set globally on the AWS.config object or per service by passing the credential information to the service object directly.

For more information on different ways to set credentials in your SDK, refer to: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html